# How to import specific column from all the excel files and export it as a table in new excel file?

Tags: excel, powershell

```
$excel_test = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application

$excel_test.visible =$false
$excel_test.DisplayAlerts =$true

$excelFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\Lab-User\Documents\NDVI_2_Working -Include *.xlsx -Recurse

    Foreach ($file in $excelFiles)
                            {
                               $workbook = $excel_test.Workbooks.open($file)
                               $Worksheet = $Workbook.WorkSheets.item("Sheet2")
                               $range = $WorkSheet.range("A1:AC1").EntireColumn 
                               $averages=$range.Copy("AB1").EntireColumn 
    $averages.SaveAs("C:\Users\Lab-User\Documents\NDVI_2_Working\Summary.xlsx")
                       }
```

I keep getting the error that says "Copy method of range class failed".

Comment: Which line are you getting that on?

Comment: Thank you for the code and error, but please provide additional details of what you expect your output to be. I don't think the Copy method has an EntireColumn property, and you are trying to perform a SaveAs method on that, which if anything would be a Range object, not a Workbook object so it isn't going to have a SaveAs method. I honestly think you need to scrap most of what you have in the ForEach loop and try again. Consider making a new workbook, and then using `$Averages = $Worksheet.UsedRange.Columns.Item("AB").EntireColumn` and then use $Averages.Copy() to paste into the new workbook.

Comment: There are 23 xlms files. Each one has multiple columns. What I am interested in is column "AB" (which is specified in the code). I want each AB column from all the 23 xlms files to be output in new xlms file. I want this new xlms file to be called "Summary.xlms".